# How to modify a html textview value with java

Tags: java, html

I am in a project in which i have to modify a html file's textview with java.

In java I have a value in a `String` as follows

```
String a ="HAI";
```

I have to set this `"HAI"` to a html `textfield`.

How to do this.

Any help should be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you use Servlets, JSP or JSF?

Comment: You can't set a value from java class to a plain html

Comment: Unless that HTML contains some Javascript..

Comment: I did it with Javascript.Thank u all for your feedbacks.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do that in plain java, Unless you consider HTML as plan text and do text edit,
Use JavaScript or JQuery

Comment: Thank u for your valuable feedback.